MacBook Pro M2 fan spinning erratically
My MacBook Pro with an M2 chip has its fans spinning erratically even when no resource-intensive programs are running, but the body of the laptop is cold.
Recently, I had the motherboard and screen replaced at the Genius Bar, and the system has been upgraded to version 14.5, but the issue remains unresolved.
Has anyone encountered this situation? Or where should I start troubleshooting this problem? During this period, the laptop is functioning normally.
The screenshots of the cpu and energy usage as follows


Was the reason of the motherboard/screen replacement related to the fan issue? Did you mention the fan problem at the Genius Bar, what was their response? When the fans are running, what do you see in Activity Monitor in terms of CPU and Energy usage (please add screenshots)?

Yes, if the fans are working erratically after they've opened it up, I'd take it back to the Apple Store. What happened to it in the first place?

@ nohillside Regarding the specific reasons for the motherboard and screen replacement at the Genius Bar, I did not get any details. I just tried the "Erase All Contents and Settings" option and reinstalled macOS, but the issue remains unresolved. The screenshots of the CPU and energy usage have been added to the post.

@benwiggy The initial reason I went to the Genius Bar was because of this fan issue.

So, you went to the Genius Bar because of this fan issue; they replaced the motherboard and the screen (???), and the fan issue remains...?

Basically, after the motherboard was replaced, it worked fine for a few days but then the issue reappeared.

I would take it back to the Store, obvously they didn't fix the issue yet.

Faulty Mac is faulty. Ask them for a replacement, not a repair.

I will try it tomorrow, thanks.
